# Invalid Syntax error in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, spyder

```
runfile('C:/Users/kesha/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/kesha')
File "C:/Users/kesha/untitled0.py", line 50
labely = 'Theta3'
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand what's wrong with assigning 'Theta3' to labely variable.  There are no errors when assign 'Theta2' or 'Theta1' to labely variable.  I'm pretty sure it's not a name dependency either because I switched the name with no success. Thank you for your time and attention.

Here is the code snippet:

```
titleP = 'Amplitude of Pendulum vs. Time'
labelx = 'Time in Seconds'

labely = 'Theta1'
t,th1,E1 = calc(np.pi/12)
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)

labely = 'Theta2'
t,th2,E2 = calc(np.pi/6)
plot2d(plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)

labely = 'Theta3'
t,th3,E3 = calc(np.pi/3)
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)
```

Comment: there's probably an error on the line *right before the assignment*. Edit your question and include the full code snippet you're trying to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an typo error `labely = 'Theta2'` block.

Replace `plot2d(plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)` with `plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)` to resolve the error.

```
titleP = 'Amplitude of Pendulum vs. Time'
labelx = 'Time in Seconds'

labely = 'Theta1'
t,th1,E1 = calc(np.pi/12)
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)

labely = 'Theta2'
t,th2,E2 = calc(np.pi/6)
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t) # replaced

labely = 'Theta3'
t,th3,E3 = calc(np.pi/3)
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)
```

Answer (score 0):

missing braces...

```
# bad
plot2d(plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t) # <= ")" is missing

# good
plot2d(labelx, labely, titleP, -1, 0, 1, t)
```